# Density plot starts earlier than the available data

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have generated a density plot that displays the distribution of two drugs over a period of time. The dataset contains 3 columns, including patient ID, date of prescription, and drug name. The earliest prescription for drug A in the database is dated 2003-11-04, while for drug B, it is 2012-01-31. However, the plot for drug B appears to start before Jan-2012 which is quite odd.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K3tyQ.png)

To create the plot, I used the code below along with the geom_density function. I'm not sure why this is happening. Does anyone have any ideas?

```
drugs %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x=date, fill=drug_name, colour=drug_name)) +
    geom_density(alpha=0.5)+
    theme_minimal()+
    scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 year", 
                 date_labels = "%Y")+
    labs(x = "Years", y = "Density")
```

Comment: Try passing `trim = TRUE` to `geom_density()`.

Comment: Thanks a lot @joran, this made the trick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The densities are by default calculated on the full range of the data for both groups.

Pass `trim = TRUE` to `geom_density()` to calculate the densities on the range of each group separately.